# Extracting the Place and Publisher in a String of Sentence

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

So I have a list of Data Stating the Place and Publisher of a Journal

The Data is given in a single Sentence in a List

```py
['Place: Amsterdam Publisher: Elsevier Science Bv WOS:000179813800003' ,
 'Place: Hanoi Publisher: Vietnam Acad Science & Technology-Vast WOS:000530921100003' , 
 'Publisher: SAGE Publications Ltd',
 'Place: London']
```

So as you can see in some strings Publisher is given but no place and some places it can be vice versa.

So I want the Output to be like in two lists

```py
Places = ['Amsterdam','Hanoi','London']
Publishers = ['Elsevier Science',
              'Vietnam Acad Science & Technology- Vast',
              'SAGE Publications Ltd']
```

I am Using Python for this Data analysis..

I was thinking of using split() function to detect location  of Place is written and chose the string next to it but it seems not to be working

My Code till Now

```
places=[]
for i in extrainfo :  #E xtrainfo Name of Initial List 
 
 if ('Place') in i :
       z=i
       i=i.split()
       counter=0
       for q in i :
        if q=='Place' :
          break
        counter=counter+1
 places=pleaces+z[counter+1]       
print(places)
```

Comment: Can you share the code you already have?

Comment: Also that isn't a single sentence in a list, that is a list of strings

Comment: Hi! Interesting problem. Can you explain how you know that the second publisher is `'Vietnam Acad Science & Technology'` and not `'Vietnam Acad Science & Technology-Vast'`?

Comment: @Stef Yes it is Vietnam Acad Science & Technology-Vast Sorry for the error

Comment: Can you have entries only having the `Publisher` like `'Publisher: SAGE Publications Ltd'`, and no place?

Comment: @speeder1987 its not working ill share

Comment: places=[]
    for i in extrainfo :
     
     if ('Place') in i :
           z=i
           i=i.split()
           counter=0
           for q in i :
            if q=='Place' :
              break
            counter=counter+1
     places=pleaces+z[counter+1]       
    print(places)

Comment: Sorry Check the Edit in the Post for my Code Version

Comment: Can you explain how you know that the fist publisher is `'Elsevier Science'` and not `'Elsevier Science Bv'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- split on colons `':'` using `s.split(':')`;
- discard trailing whitespace using `s.strip()`;
- if one of the split substrings ends with `'Publisher'` or `'Place'`, add the next substring to the relevant list;
- some of the substrings added to the lists will end with `'Place'` or `'Publisher'`: take care of that using `s.removesuffix('Place').removesuffix('Publisher')`.

```py
from itertools import pairwise # python>=3.10
# from itertools import tee
# def pairwise(iterable):
#     "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
#     a, b = tee(iterable)
#     next(b, None)
#     return zip(a, b)

data = ['Place: Amsterdam Publisher: Elsevier Science Bv WOS:000179813800003' , 'Place: Hanoi Publisher: Vietnam Acad Science & Technology-Vast WOS:000530921100003' , 'Publisher: SAGE Publications Ltd','Place: London']

things = {'Place': [], 'Publisher': [], 'WOS': []}

for sentence in data:
    for k, v in pairwise(map(str.strip, sentence.split(':'))):
        for cat in things:
            if k.endswith(cat):
                for suffix in things:
                    v = v.removesuffix(suffix).strip()
                things[cat].append(v)
                break

print(things)
# {'Place': ['Amsterdam', 'Hanoi', 'London'],
#  'Publisher': ['Elsevier Science Bv', 'Vietnam Acad Science & Technology-Vast', 'SAGE Publications Ltd'],
#  'WOS': ['000179813800003', '000530921100003']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `re` module:

```py
import re

lst = [
    "Place: Amsterdam Publisher: Elsevier Science Bv WOS:000179813800003",
    "Place: Hanoi Publisher: Vietnam Acad Science & Technology-Vast WOS:000530921100003",
    "Publisher: SAGE Publications Ltd",
    "Place: London",
]

places = [
    m.group(1)
    for i in lst
    if (m := re.search(r"Place: (.*?)\s*(?:Publisher|$)", i))
]

publishers = [
    m.group(1)
    for i in lst
    if (m := re.search(r"Publisher: (.*?)\s*(?:WOS|$)", i))
]

print(places)
print(publishers)
```

Prints:

```py
['Amsterdam', 'Hanoi', 'London']
['Elsevier Science Bv', 'Vietnam Acad Science & Technology-Vast', 'SAGE Publications Ltd']
```

Comment: Hi! I think it's always useful to point out any assumptions made in an answer, if those assumptions are not explicit in the OP's question. For instance, here you assumed that "Place" can only be followed by "Publisher" or nothing, and that "Publisher" can only be followed by "WOS" or nothing. In particular, "Publisher" cannot be followed by "Place". I think it's worth stating that assumption explicitly in your answer, so that if someone tries to apply your code in a situation where that assumption doesn't hold, they'll be warned.